# Ember js & handlebars - each not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm trying to get my head around it.

I have the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/6wPmW/ for a working example):

```
     <script type="text/x-handlebars">
                    <div id="ViewAddresses" class="location_search_results selected_searches clearfix">

                        <div>

                                    <div>
                                    {{#each MapSearch.ViewAddressesC}}
                                        <div class="row">ghfdg</div>
                                    {{/each}}
                                    </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </script>​
```

JS:

```
MapSearch = Ember.Application.create();
MapSearch.ListAddress = Ember.Object.extend({
    list_info: null,
    node_level: null,
    node_value: null,
    removed_properties: null

});
MapSearch.ViewAddressListC = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    initialize: function() {
        me = this;
        var l = MapSearch.ListAddress.create({
            node_level: "test",
            node_value: "test"
        });
        me.pushObject(l);
        var l = MapSearch.ListAddress.create({
            node_level: "test",
            node_value: "test"
        });
        me.pushObject(l);
        console.log(me);
    }

});
MapSearch.ViewAddressListC.initialize();
console.log(MapSearch.ViewAddressListC.get("content"));​
```

Surely I should get two `<divs>` created from the each loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your template:

```
{{#each MapSearch.ViewAddressesC}}
```

should be

```
{{#each MapSearch.ViewAddressListC}}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mXjD9/).

Comment: God. Damn. It. 3 hours.... 3 hours I spent... all for a typo! Thanks so much man.

Comment: Too bad... but don't worry, the more you will play with Ember.js, the quickest you will resolve this kind of issue

Comment: Yea.  I'm really feeling my way around it at the moment. It seems quite easy to pick up but sometimes so easy that I feel like I'm doing things the wrong way. Practice makes perfect though, its an awesome framework.